# How to execute SQL statement in Pipeline script of Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have created on pipeline and I want to execute one sql query in it. I have written following statements(Only two Lines of code, no imports/Class etc.) and throws error while executing it.

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://myIP:3306/dbName", "uname","password", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
sql.execute "select count(*) from TableName"
```

I am getting this error

```
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod groovy.sql.Sql newInstance java.lang.String java.lang.String java.lang.String java.lang.String
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.whitelists.StaticWhitelist.rejectStaticMethod(StaticWhitelist.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onStaticCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:142)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$2.call(Checker.java:180)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedStaticCall(Checker.java:177)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:91)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:15)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:3)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:106)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor841.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:19)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:164)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:277)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$000(CpsThreadGroup.java:77)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:186)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:184)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Pls help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

From the error it looks like you are running the script in sandbox mode, in which case there are a lot of limitation what you can execute in the script. For example the following wont work neither:

```
echo binding.hasVariable("test")
```

The things you can do:

- If you are **not** hosting the Jenkins yourself you cannot do much from the pipeline script itself, you have to create a separate process to do the `select` you want to do and pass back the result to the pipeline script. You can do this by adding a groovy script to the slave and executing it from the pipeline, for example.

All scenarios below assume that you are hosing Jenkins yourself

- If you are using `Pipeline script` definition you have the option to run the script **not** in sandbox mode (uncheck `Use Groovy Sandbox` in the job configuration page). In this case if you are **an admin** it should work just fine. If you are **not an admin** follow the advice below
- If you are using `Pipeline script from SCM` definition, then the script **will be** executed in `sandbox` mode and you will also encounter the error you posted. Then an admin needs to go to **Manage Jenkins » In-process Script Approval** and approve the method call that was denied (just press the `Approve` button)

Note: The above was tested on Jenkins version: 2.7.1

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gergely. but I m not that much familiar with Jenkins. I just created on Pipeline > Navigate to 'Configure' page > Add above code in 'Pipeline - Script' > Apply and Build it.

- Groovy Sandbox option in the job configuration page is already unchecked.
- I have approved Manage Jenkins » In-process Script Approval method calls.

While running using (Build Now) it gives this error
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver